# Why does the code output shows address of integer after performing pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include<stdio.h> 

    int main(){
    int i=30;
    int *ptr=&i;
    printf("Value of i is %d\n",*ptr);
    ptr++;
    printf("Value of i is %d\n",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

//OUTPUT:-

Value of i is 30

Value of i is 6618648

Comment: How do you know it is the address of the integer? Anyway, the code is invalid because the result of incrementing and accessing a pointer beyond the bounds of the variable it points to is undefined behaviour.

Comment: read the dupes. Consider `i` as a single element integer array.

Comment: It is `(*ptr)++`, not what you wrote.